# I want to use the C# Convert.ToBase64String method in WordPress instead of the WordPress one

Tags: c#, php, wordpress

I'm trying to transfer the Worpdress HashPassword method to C#, and now stuck with Encode64 method.

```
private const string ITOA64 = "./0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";


private string Encode64(IReadOnlyList<byte> input, int count) 
{
    var stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    var iteration = 0;
    do {
        int value = (int)input[iteration++];
        stringBuilder.Append(ITOA64[value & 0x3f]);
        
        if (iteration < count)
            value = value | ((int)input[iteration] << 8);
        
        stringBuilder.Append(ITOA64[(value >> 6) & 0x3f]);
        
        if (iteration++ >= count)
            break;
        
        if (iteration < count)
            value = value | ((int)input[iteration] << 16);
        
        stringBuilder.Append(ITOA64[(value >> 12) & 0x3f]);
        
        if (iteration++ >= count)
            break;
        
        stringBuilder.Append(ITOA64[(value >> 18) & 0x3f]);
    } while (iteration < count);

    return stringBuilder.ToString();
}
```

PHP version:

```
    function encode64($input, $count)
    {
        $output = '';
        $i = 0;
        do {
            $value = ord($input[$i++]);
            $output .= $this->itoa64[$value & 0x3f];
            if ($i < $count)
                $value |= ord($input[$i]) << 8;
            $output .= $this->itoa64[($value >> 6) & 0x3f];
            if ($i++ >= $count)
                break;
            if ($i < $count)
                $value |= ord($input[$i]) << 16;
            $output .= $this->itoa64[($value >> 12) & 0x3f];
            if ($i++ >= $count)
                break;
            $output .= $this->itoa64[($value >> 18) & 0x3f];
        } while ($i < $count);

        return $output;
    }
```

In WP this method used like: `$this->encode64($hash, 16);`, where `$hash` it's             `$hash = md5($salt . $password, TRUE);`
salt and password is strings.

I want to replace this Encode64 method with an internal C# method, I found that I can use `Convert.ToBase64String` for this:

`Convert.ToBase64String(salt + hash, 0, 16)`

But the problem is that `Encode64` and `Convert.ToBase64String` gives different results, at least different lengths:

Encode64: `$Z$Z9pm.hE4ZCjjicyMuMp2lmIARPnY3k/`

Convert.ToBase64String: `$Z$Z9pm.hE4Zzvu6qI/pWE1EMsV020wSaZ==`

How to fix it?

Comment: .NET uses the RFC 2045 form of Base64 (Base64 transfer encoding for MIME). You therefore want the same in PHP. That seems to be [the default](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.base64-encode.php) in PHP. I'm therefore confused by your question as it would appear that PHP already has the necessary method.

Comment: @Llama I want to get the same functionality from PHP to C#.

Comment: Your question states that you want to use the C# method in PHP...

Comment: @Llama, read please, title and first part: I'm trying to transfer the Worpdress HashPassword method to C#, and now stuck with Encode64 method.

Comment: Your question title says _"Replace Wordpress Encode64 method with C# Convert.ToBase64String?"_ - as in "I want to use the C# Convert.ToBase64String method in WordPress instead of the WordPress one."

Comment: Anyway, whatever you're trying to do, you haven't shown us the PHP base64 method from WordPress, so how could we possibly see what's wrong?

Comment: @Llama, anyway, excuse me, I'm wrong.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239718/discussion-between-getunstuck-and-llama).

Comment: *want to replace this Encode64 method with an internal C# method* - why?

Comment: @CaiusJard for more clear code and using quality internal functional instead of copying functional from PHP.

Comment: It seems highly unlikely that WordPress' specific flavour of base64 (which is unlike those listed on the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64)) will have an existing implementation in .NET's built-in libraries. It might exist as a third party NuGet package though.

Comment: So the implementation you have works, you want to change it to use Convert.ToBase64String, they give different results, and you're wondering why. A good first step would be to do some deep dive research on this, get [the source code to Convert](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/convert.cs,6089a930276e17f5) and look at how the two methods differ... tbh I'd just stick with the working code you have and move onto the next problem; sometimes life is too short to spend hours poring over something like this only to conclude that they're fundamentally different